# $routeProviderのresolveでリソースの取得中、ローディングイメージを表示したい

Tags: javascript, angularjs

### AngularJSについての質問です。

$routeProviderのresolveにおいて、controllerが依存するリソースをRESTAPIで取得しています。
このリソースの取得処理が完了するまでの間、ページ遷移が保留状態となり画面が硬直してしまいます。
この間、ユーザは何が起こっているか分からないので、通信中であることを示すローディングイメージを表示したいと考えています。

---

また、ローディングイメージについては遷移先や遷移元のビューに埋め込むのではなく、独立したローディングビューを用意しそれをページ遷移の間に挟むようにしたいと考えています。

---

上記を実現する方法、または一般的なベストプラクティスがあればお教え下さい。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AngularJS`は使ったことがなく、もっぱら`jQuery TOOLS`で`overlay`しますが･･･
`AngularOverlay Directive`はどうですか？ライセンスはMITのようです。

参考URL：
[AngularOverlay Directive](https://www.google.co.jp/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FDanWahlin%2FAngularOverlay&ei=qpfJVIQalfHyBemtgYAI&usg=AFQjCNF4-pbUTPpxINShUjSKafmaBz-yzw&bvm=bv.84607526,d.dGc)
[AngularJSでAjaxリクエスト中にLoading画像を表示](http://dim5.net/angularjs/ajax-request-overlay.html)

Comment: ありがとうございます。実現したいことにかなり近いです。ただ、今試せる環境にないので確認できていないのですが、すべての$httpのリクエストにフックしてしまうように見えます。特定のリクエストの場合のみフックするようにコントロールできればベストなのですが…

Comment: すみません。上記のコメントは誤りでした。特定のリクエストに限定することができるようです。失礼しました。回答ありがとうございました。